how to connect to master db in azure sql using python
I am trying to connect to the master database in Azure SQL using Python . I need to create a login and perform some administrative tasks like assigning roles. However, when I try to connect to the database using the name "master", it fails, and I receive a connection error.

I'm not entirely sure I've understood the question correctly, but here's my best attempt at an answer.
You can use the pyodbc library. An example of its usage is provided in the link. Connecting to SQL using pyodbc
Please provide the code you are trying to run and the error message you are encountering. This will help us (me) better understand the issue and help you out.
